# Microsoft SQL: How to select two queries reult in one

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I want to select HighRisk, MediumRisk and so on low risk etc in one row result, The issue is MicrosoftSQL server format i am not aware of

```
Select HighRisk , MediumRisk from
(
Select  count(Distinct(PatientKey)) as HighRisk from dbo.vw_FactReferral a
where   (a.PrescriptionDueDateKey <= Cast(FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd') as int)   
         AND a.OrderConfirmationDueDateKey <= Cast(FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd') as int)
 AND a.NextDeliveryDueDateKey <= Cast(FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd') as int)) as HR
,
 Select  count(Distinct(PatientKey)) as MediumRisk from dbo.vw_FactReferral a
where   (a.PrescriptionDueDateKey <= Cast(FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd') as int)  
         AND a.OrderConfirmationDueDateKey <= Cast(FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd') as int)
 AND a.NextDeliveryDueDateKey <= Cast(FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd') as int)) as HM
 )a
```

Comment: Sample data, and expected results will help us help you. Also, *why* are you converting `GETDATE()` to an `int`? That sounds like a problem. Dates *aren't* numbers.

Comment: is it same logic for both high na medium?

Comment: I suggest using PIVOT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: in SQL Server, you can use store procedure, 1st declare  variable and query out put put this variable and finally select all variable in on query.

Comment: Just replace the "," between the two queries within the sub query with "UNION ALL"...

Comment: What is the difference between high, medium and low? Side notes: to truncate `datetime` to `date`, just `cast(getdate() as date)`. And `DISTINCT` is not a function